# Can I change the format of an animation while it's rendering?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I know this may sound like a silly question but I started to render an animation, but I accidentally kept it on .AVI and is supposed to be on MPEG-4. Is it okay if I change the format while it's rendering?

Answer (score 7):

**no**, this isn't supported, and likely wont be (does any software do this?).

You may want to render images and encode after.

Answer (score 5):

I just did a test 40-frame render where I started a render with AVI and after about half way switched it to MPEG-4 and the resulting .avi file was not corrupted and played fine. It looks like it's one of those parameters like tile size that Blender only reads at the start of a render and won't switch it on the fly as it renders an animation. (In other words, you'll be getting an AVI file in the end, not MPEG-4.)

Settings like motion blur can be switched while rendering is going on and changes appear to take affect on the next frame to be rendered.

It sounds like you may be rendering frames directly to a video format. If that's the case, you should look at rendering individual frames as image files (say, PNG) and then using the Video Sequencer to put the resulting files into a video format.